# Scansion. Vocabulary

Tags: rhythm, lyrics

So I'm trying to get into poetry and using scansion to understand I guess the rhythm.  MY question is what do you call it when you have a line with different stresses and unstressed syllables?

For instance, if I say

```
  /   u    u / u    u  /    u /  /
"I'm down in a rut, a pain in my gut"
```

This line doesn't have an even amount of stresses and unstresses
as if it was

```
  u   /    u /  u    /  u   /  u  /
"I'm down in a rut, a pain in my gut"
```

What would this be called?

Comment: I'd naturally emphasize "I'm down in a rut, a pain in my gut" as u / u u / (beat) u / u u / or u / (beat) u u / (beat) / (beat) / (beat) u u / .

Comment: what would it be called though?

Comment: I’m not sure this is really about music practice or theory. What we call it in music may not be what it’s called in poetry.

Comment: @b3ko nailed it.  Look up things like  "iambic pentameter" and "trochaic heptameter" to get a start on learning the lingo used to describe poetic meters.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a poetry question.

Comment: It's a poetry question to help me with writing lyrics for music.  Getting better with rhythm.

Comment: You can’t choose how you stress the same words like that. The words have an inherent stress pattern that is almost always not optional. In the example phrase, *down*, *rut*, *pain*, and *gut* should always be considered stressed syllables, and the rest are unstressed. The word *in* is almost never stressed.

Comment: This question is possibly also on-topic at https://writing.stackexchange.com. Here it’s maybe borderline. I personally think it’s at least close to being on-topic here because the prosody of setting lyrics to music seems on-topic here and would not be on the Writing Stack, and I think this question is really about that process even if it’s not clearly about that.

Comment: @todd_wilcox true. However, if asking for specific names of something that happens in poetry, which is how I read this, it’s not in topic.

Answer (score 5):

A poetic [foot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foot_(prosody)) need not have an even number of syllables, and a poetic line need not have an even number of feet.  Furthermore, in some styles of poetry, if not most, it is not uncommon to vary the rhythm somewhat by inserting a three-syllable foot in a two-syllable meter or vice versa.

A famous example, set many times to music, most famously by Schubert, is Goethe's *Erlkönig,* which begins

> Wer reitet so spät durch Nacht und Wind?
>   Es ist der Vater mit seinem Kind;

The scansion is

> u / u u / u / u /
>   u / u / u u / u /

There is an "extra" unstressed syllable in each line, and the position of the extra unstressed syllable is different.

A quick scan of the Wikipedia article on [prosody](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metre_(poetry)) suggests that there is no other term for this than "metric variation."